# Repeat interval by local notification

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I want to set up a local notification with custom fireDate. It should send a push up every Sunday and Monday at 7.00 pm. I live in europa. Do I have to pay attention to something because of the week calendar?

My code looks at the moment like that:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear |   NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute| NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitWeekday) fromDate: now];

[componentsForFireDate setWeekday: 1] ;
[componentsForFireDate setHour: 19] ;
[componentsForFireDate setMinute:22] ;
[componentsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;

NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForFireDate];

// Create the notification
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;

notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification ;
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Wake up"] ;

notification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

**Edit:**

I logged the fireDate (2015-01-01 18:22:00 +0000). First it is one hour to early, second something is wrong with the date)

Comment: 1: NSLog always prints the GMT value of the date which seems to be 1 hour behind your local time. 2: You have not provided any date. So you can not expect a date to be printed. What is your problem, the date or the repetition or both?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Both. I logged my notification (<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7fbb58c2a500>{fire date = Thursday, January 1, 2015 at 7:22:00 PM Central European Standard Time, repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = (null), user info = (null)})
The time is correct, but the is date wrong. Because them it will not working. My second question is, how would i put two days in to "setWeekday"? Maybe like that ([componentsForFireDate setWeekday: 1 & 2];)?

Comment: Actually what you are looking for is an event([EventKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/)) not notification. Notification can be fired only once on a particular fire date.